# Image alignment, plugin jQuery Lightbox repeated viewing images, and link in <h2> <p>? Why?

Tags: jquery, css, html, lightbox, image

I have **three questions** on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/85unG/5/light/) page:

1. Why the `h2` and `p` tags is a link?
2. How do I align the image on the left, so lean in the content div.
3. Why when you click on the image to lightbox plugin displays several images again? Note that the `ul` and `li` tags are not repeated images.

By moving to the next picture he is repeating images.
Note that the 16 footer he accuses images, and the total is 6 images

Thanks!

Comment: Sweet mother of grammar! I am so confused right now. Could you possibly rephrase this in a more readable way?

Comment: `<a href="http://bit.ly/eadRzx" title="My! :)" />` you can't do that, do this instead: `<a href="http://bit.ly/eadRzx" title="My! :)"></a>` this will fix the first problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved your first two issues here:

1. Please make complete end tag there:

   ```
   <a href="http://bit.ly/hGCPhT" title="Compact" /></a>
   ```
2. Add `padding-left` CSS to 0 in parent `<ul>` of that image.